# how can I change an XML object from javascript, not just a copy of its value?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, reference

I have some XML `clientXML` and I would like to replace one `<issue>` (including everything nested within the issue). The new `<issue>` is called `newXMLIssue`. I have pinpointed the issue to replace with

```
var oldXMLIssue = clientXML.querySelector("[XMLId=" + XMLIssueId + "]");
```

replaced it with

```
oldXMLIssue = newXMLIssue;
```

but I believe this has only replaced a copy of the object because

```
alert(oldXMLIssue.childNodes[2].textContent);
```

outputs the new info (stuff I want), but

```
alert(clientXML.querySelector("[XMLId=" + XMLIssueId + "]").childNodes[2].textContent);
```

still outputs only the old information. (both alert statements should output the same).

How can I change the object itself, and not just a copy of it?

Comment: Assigning a variable doesn't change anything.  You need to use the DOM APIs.

Comment: how do i grab a reference to it then? I cant use `clientXML.querySelector("[XMLId=" + XMLIssueId + "]")` on the left side of any equations...

Comment: I really dont know what that means. I googled DOM APIs and still couldnt figure out the answer. I found `
x.removeChild(element)` and `x.appendChild(element)` but i still would need to assign the object to a variable "element". Can you elaborate?